# IllegalMonitorStateException when sharing the object

Tags: multithreading

I am trying to create single variable producer consumer solution , but I am getting IllegalMonitorStateException in Producer's notifyAll() method.
I am acquiring the lock in synchronized block as well , what might have gone wrong ?

```
/**
 * Write a description of class SingleProducerConsumer here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class SingleProdCons
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Integer x = 0;
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(x),"Producer");
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(x),"Consumer");
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
    }    
}

  class Producer implements Runnable
    {
        private Integer x;

        Producer(Integer x)
        {
            this.x = x;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
             synchronized(x)
            {
            while(x.equals(0)==false){

                //The value of the variable has not been consumed yet , we should wait here till it gets consumed
                try{
                x.wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException ie)
                {
                    System.out.println("Caught Exception : "+ie.getMessage());
                }

            }

            //Else initialze the variable and let it get used by the Consumer then
            synchronized(x)
            {
                x=10;
                x.notifyAll();

            }
        }

        }

    }

    class Consumer implements Runnable
    {
        private Integer x;

        Consumer(Integer x)
        {
            this.x = x;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            synchronized(x)
            {
            while(x.equals(0)==true)
            {
                //The value has not been put by the Producer thread yet hence we should wait here
                System.out.println("We are before the method call of the wait on the x object");
                try{
                x.wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException ie)
                {
                    System.out.println("Caught the exception : "+ie.getMessage());
                }
            }
           }

           synchronized(x)
           {
               System.out.println("Consuming : "+x);
               x.notifyAll();
           }

        }

    }

Exception in thread "Producer" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at Producer.run(SingleProdCons.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Producer" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at Producer.run(SingleProdCons.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Producer" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at Producer.run(SingleProdCons.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Producer" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at Producer.run(SingleProdCons.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
synchronized(x)
{
    x=10;
    x.notifyAll();
}
```

It's important to understand that you don't synchronize on a *variable* - you synchronize on an *object*. So you're modify the value of `x` to refer to a different `Integer` object, and you're then calling `notifyAll` on that different object... from a thread which doesn't own the monitor for that object.

I'd strongly advise you not to use `Integer` objects for synchronization at all. Ideally, use an object which isn't used for *any* other purpose - that makes it easier to reason about.

You can still have your `x` variable, and document that it shouldn't be modified other than when the thread holds the appropriate lock - but make it independent from the lock itself.

Comment: Well this sounds cool, but what do you mean by not used for any other purpose.If I use private final Vector sharedQueue it works nicely. :)

Comment: @Chetan: I mean that you only use it for synchronization/wait/notify purposes... which means you can have a single object, even if the values that it's "guarding" are modified. I would strongly advise *against* using a `Vector` for example, because operations on `Vector` are themselves synchronized, intefering with whatever you're also doing. As soon as you have to start worrying about what other code is going to acquire/release (and possibly notify/wait) the monitor, it's harder to reason about your code.

Comment: Do you mean to use different variable for modification and for wait/notify purpose there will be different varaible ?

Comment: I still feel I am modifying the single objects only.

Comment: @Chetan: No, you're not. When you write `x = 10;` you're changing the value of `x` to refer to a different object. It's really important that you understand the difference between variables, references and objects.

Comment: Yeah , but it would be helpful If you can provide some source or links where I can refer to understand and solve this problem

Comment: @Chetan: Well it's hard to give a specific example as I'd normally have a shared object to communicate between the producer and consumer, and in fact I'd probably use a `BlockingQueue` or something else from `java.util.concurrent`... in other words, it would be a significant change in design from what you've currently got. But you should be able to understand what's going wrong with your current code just from the description in the answer